# How to replace a particular string/text in all views in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have project in MVC. I which there are hundreds of views which contain a string. I want to replace a string/word (Example "Some thing" into "Something") in all views but not in controller or model. Is it possible to change it only in all views?

Answer (score 2):

1. In Visual Studio, open the `Find in Files` dialog with `Ctrl+Shift+F` or from the menu `Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files`.
2. At the top, select `Find in Files` or `Replace in Files`.
3. Enter what you want to search for in the `Find` input.
4. The `File types` input lets you set the search to only look in certain file types. For views, you could use `*.cshtml`.
5. Click `Find All` to see the results.

[image]